# c# how to access enum constant names from another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, enums

I have enum in one form and I'd like to access the integer constant names from another form opened by this form as they share some constants.

```
    public enum Commands
    {
        NOP = 0,
        READ_VOLTAGE = 1,
        READ_OSC = 2,
        READ_FAST = 3,
        READ_VREF = 4,
        SET_VREF_INT = 5,
    }
```

As the integer constant name I understand for example `READ_FAST`

Comment: inside     `public partial class Visualize : Form`

Comment: People do not like my question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that the `public enum` declaration is nested in the other form. You can access it by qualifying the `enum` with the enclosing type name (the form name here):

```
AnotherForm.Commands.READ_FAST
```

Another option is to extract the `enum` declaration into its own file. I often also put all enums in one file called "Enum.cs". Then you will be able to access it with:

```
Commands.READ_FAST
```

But in any case you must qualify the constant name with the `enum` name.

Comment: I have tried the the first sollution but for some reasons I cant access this enum. But the second idea is actually OK :). Thank you

Comment: The first solution only works if the enum is embedded in the form class. If it is above the form class, then solution 2 works (without extracting it to another file).